# I don't know how to find .exe with numbers in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

For example, I would like to find an 'exe' with a fixed path: **\Temp\3038.exe**

The number before '.exe' is fixed to 4 digits, but the value is random(0001 ~ 9999).

Only numbers are changed to 4 random digits.
I'd really appreciate it if you could tell me what to do.

I tried 2ways:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE path REGEXP '\\Temp\\\d{4}.exe';
```

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE path like '\\Temp\\\d{4}.exe';
```

my data:

```
C:\\Users\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\1536.exe
C:\\Users\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\6247.exe
C:\\Users\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\2508.exe
.......(skip)
```

For these I need to get **1536**, **6247**, **2508**

Comment: Have you looked into using [REGEXP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) in order to match the filename via a regular expression? Even a simple `\\Temp\\\d{4}.exe` should do it.

Comment: I haven't learned SQL properly yet, so I don't understand REGEXP yet. I did d{4}.exe as you told me, but I couldn't find any results. Can you give me some more advice?

Comment: An advice would be: Use [edit] to add the thing your tried to your question.

Answer (score 0):

[DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e6d407481bcfcd74c552d699c9bee694)

A regular expression will bite, especially if it has a '` in it.

When you say the data is: `C:\\Users\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\2508.exe` will it have one '` or two '' ?  to be honest i got a but lost too

The DBFIDDLE uses:

```
select * 
from mytable 
where path REGEXP '.*\\\\Temp\\\\\\d{4}.exe';
```

The REGEXP looks complicated, but let me try to explain, it matches

- `.*` a dot is any character, and an asterix says that character(s) can be present 0 or more times.
- `\\` a backslash
- `\\` another backslash
- 'Temp' the four letters 'T','e','m' and 'p', in this order.
- `\\` another backslash
- `\\` another backslash
- `\d{4}` the `\d` is representing a digit (which is a number between 0 and 9), and the '{4}' will match four of those.
- `.`  this is a random character
- `exe` this is the three letters in 'exe'.

A *bug* in this is that this will also match: `C:\\Users\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\2508Xexe`

But, I like to keep room for improvements

P.S. When replacing the '.' by '.' it will match a dot literally, and not a random charachter.

EDIT: re-reading the question, I see that you only want the numbers.

From the results you can take `LEFT(RIGHT(path,8),4)`

This will first take the last 8 charachters (`RIGHT(path,8)`), and from that the first 4 characters.  This should work because the matching regular expression result always end in 4 numbers with '.exe' after it.

Comment: Added an explanation on how to get the numbers.